# Why the code doesn't show False in the Terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is probably a really stupid question but I don't understand why the code doesn't show `False` in the terminal. Instead it says that there is a syntax error but i don't see where i made one... I am coding in Python 3.7.5 on Visual Studio Code.

Here is my code:

```
a=int(input("What's the value of a ? "))
B = 10<=a and a<=60
B==True
```

And here is what i get in the terminal:

```
& "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64/python.exe" c:/Users/Utilisateur/workspace_louis/prog_s3/montagne_russe.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64/python.exe" c:/Users/Utilisateur/workspace_louis/prog_s3/montagne_russe.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The error probably has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Please take some time to actually *read* the error message. It seems that it's not a problem with the script but how you attempt to run it, i.e. a configuration problem.

Comment: The code works at my Spyder-Anaconda... Maybe it is not a problem of Python script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But whats the problem with the way i attempt to run it? How can i fix the configuration? @Some programmer dude

Comment: @Louis It looks like it's trying to run a Windows shell (CMD) command as a Python command. I don't use VSC though so I don't know why, sorry. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you! Sorry but I don't know what is a Windows shell command..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the run configuration file. The error is most likely there.

Comment: How are you running this code? Were you in the REPL when you ran this? You're missing a prompt in that example you have provided either from Python's REPL or from the shell.

Comment: Your log seems like incomplete. Could you post more detailed log?

Comment: And you can also try switch a environment to execute the codes instead of using Visual Studio Python

Answer (score -2):

Because you aren't printing it. Try:

```
a=int(input("What's the value of a ? "))
B = 10<=a and a<=60
print(B==True)
```

Comment: OP's experiencing a *syntax error*, not missing output

Comment: When programming in the Terminal, you don't need an explicit print statement.